# Where do the electrons in lead–acid battery come from?

Tags: electrochemistry, solutions, electrons, hydrogen

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{PbO2 + H2SO4 &-> PbSO4 + H2O + O} &\quad &\text{(anode)}\\
\ce{Pb + H2SO4 &-> PbSO4 + H2} &\quad &\text{(cathode)}
\end{align}
$$

The cathode’s $\ce{H2}$ joins the anode’s $\ce{O}$ making $\ce{H2O}$ in solution. 
The book says the cathode gets four electrons, but from where? Two liberated hydrogens have one each, that’s two. Where’d the other two come from?

Comment: That's lead storage battery.

Comment: I adjusted the formatting of the reactions, but the first one looks wrong. It would be nice if you could add the source you've taken them from and cite the textbook.

Comment: These aren't equations for battery, but just for reactions with conc. H2SO4. @andselisk  Question could use your closehammer, I think ;)

Comment: @Mithoron I'm not sure about single-handedly closing this one. I don't think this is necessarily a bad or a homework question; it's just somewhat hard to trace the OP's reasoning in the absence of the source they took the reactions from.

Comment: @andselisk Well, that would be like "trihandedly" now ;) and it seems real unclear.

Comment: These equations look as if they had been taken from 19th century books, when ions and electrons were not yet known. In order for these former scientists to describe how Pb and PbO2 get converted into PbSO4 (without electrons), the only possibility is to admit that Pb "produces" H2 from H2SO4, and that PbO2 looses one O atom, so that both H2 and O are allowed to "combine" into H2O at the end. This is of course hard to believe today. But it was the only possibility of explaining the lead battery in the middle of the 19th century.

Answer (score 3):

The half-equations are not correctly written. There is no Oxygen atom released, and no H atom emitted, as the author proposes. And the cathode does not get 4 electrons, as he or she states. The correct half-equations should be, first at the anode : $$\ce{Pb  +  SO_4^{2-} -> PbSO4 + 2 e^-}$$ And at the cathode it is : $$\ce{PbO_2 +  4H+ + SO_4^{2-} + 2 e^- ->  PbSO_4 + 2 H2O}$$

Comment: Can we consider $\ce{PbO2}$ as a positive electrode

Comment: Yes ! $\ce{PbO_2}$  is a positive electrode.

Comment: To be fair, there is generally hydrogen release in a lead-acid battery, especially during formation, but that's not the desired reaction.